# Component with specific child aggregations in React / Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making a React component wherein I would like to have the component to have specific children.

Example like so:

```
<Toolbar>
    <ContentLeft> ...React nodes[] </ContentLeft>
    <ContentRight> ...React nodes[] </ContentRight>
</Toolbar>
```

And in the actual toolbar component, I would like to have:

```
export type ToolbarProps = {
   children?: React.ReactNode,
   contentLeft: React.ReactNode,
   contentRight: React.ReactNode
}
```

Is this possible in React (+ typescript)? The actual content of my ContentLeft and ContentRight will be dynamic, so I want to make the Toolbar component as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly make `Toolbar` to receive `ContentLeft`, `ContentRight` as props, do as below.

```
export type ToolbarProps = {
   children?: React.ReactNode,
   ContentLeft: React.ReactNode, // notice if you want Component as props, name it as PascalCase
   ContentRight: React.ReactNode
}

...

<Toolbar
    ContentLeft={<ContentLeft> {...React nodes[]} </ContentLeft>}
    ContentRight={<ContentRight> {...React nodes[]} </ContentRight>}
>
    {children}
</Toolbar>
```

or if you want to give `Toolbar` a flexibility with its props, `children` would be enough props for it.

```
export type ToolbarProps = {
   children?: React.ReactNode[], // notice that type is array
}

...

<Toolbar>
    <ContentLeft> ...React nodes[] </ContentLeft>
    <ContentRight> ...React nodes[] </ContentRight>
    <OtherComponent> ....React nodes[] </OtherComponent>
</Toolbar>
```

Comment: Hi! So it's really as props? It cannot be an actual react node?

Comment: @Kawamoto Takeshi In case you don't want it to be props, it would be just one of the `children`. It will give you more flexibility to `Toolbar`. I edited my answer so check this out.